# Rails validates_associated on destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm trying to validate an attribute in one model when I destroy another model. It's a complicated validation so I wrote a custom validation method. The problem is how do I call that validation method when I destroy the other model?

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

`validates_associated :part, :on => :destroy`

Though apparently that does not work. I've also tried doing

`before_destroy self.part.validate_method`

but that gives an undefined part.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before_destroy {|obj| obj.part.validate_method }